# Jquery sort table td not sorting currency properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am new to jquery and HTML I am trying to sort my table by currency but its not sorting properly if its currency but if its alphabetical sorting its working anyone can help me or guide me I will realy appreciate thank you in advance.My currency format has thousand separator and decimal. whenever the th is clicked the row will be sort

```js
function sortTable(f, n) {
  var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var A = getVal(a);
    var B = getVal(b);

    if (A < B) {
      return -1 * f;
    }

    if (A > B) {
      return 1 * f;
    }

    return 0;
  });

  function getVal(elm) {
    var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
    if ($.isNumeric(v)) {
      v = parseInt(v, 10);
    }

    return v;
  }

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}

var f_sl = 1;
var f_nm = 1;

$("#sl").click(function() {
  f_sl *= -1;
  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
  sortTable(f_sl, n);
});

$("#nm").click(function() {
  f_nm *= -1;
  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
  sortTable(f_nm, n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="sl">VAL</th>
      <th id="nm">name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 1,000.00</td>
      <td>AINA (W)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 20,000.00</td>
      <td>HEYZA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 5,000.15</td>
      <td>ANA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 5,000.16</td>
      <td>ZED</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should debug javascript to see what's happening? :D
I see your code is right.

Comment: Nope; If you sort by Currency, you get an order like (1, 20, 5, 5) when it should be (1, 5, 5, 20)

Comment: Wrong sort when you sort with [RM 1,000.00, RM 20,000.00, RM 5,000.15, RM 5,000.16]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), along with it's `numeric` option

Instead of:

```js
if (A < B) {
  return -1 * f;
}
if (A > B) {
  return 1 * f;
}
return 0;
```

You would use:

```js
if (f === 1) {
  return A.localeCompare(B, 'en', {numeric: true});
} else {
  return B.localeCompare(A, 'en', {numeric: true});
}
```

---

Also, `localeCompare` can handle the numerical values as *Strings*, so you don't need to `parseInt()` in your `getVal` function - The only additional change for handling Numbers is to use a Regex to remove all the `,` seperaters from your numbers while sorting; it won't have any affect after sorting, or on words

```js
function sortTable(f, n) {
  var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var A = getVal(a).replace(/(\d),(?=\d)/g, '$1');
    var B = getVal(b).replace(/(\d),(?=\d)/g, '$1');

    if (f === 1) {
      return A.localeCompare(B, 'en-UK', {
        numeric: true
      });
    } else {
      return B.localeCompare(A, 'en-UK', {
        numeric: true
      });
    }
  });

  function getVal(elm) {
    return $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
  }

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}

var f_sl = 1;
var f_nm = 1;

$("#sl").click(function() {
  f_sl *= -1;
  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
  sortTable(f_sl, n);
});

$("#nm").click(function() {
  f_nm *= -1;
  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
  sortTable(f_nm, n);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="sl">VAL</th>
      <th id="nm">name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 6,533.00</td>
      <td>AINA (W)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 20.00</td>
      <td>HEYZA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 1,174.00</td>
      <td>ANA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RM 50.16</td>
      <td>ZED</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help I tried but not sorting correctly when value changed       <table id="mytable"><thead><tr><th id="sl">VAL</th><th id="nm">name</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>RM 6,533.00</td><td>AINA (W)</td></tr><tr><td>RM 20.00</td><td>HEYZA</td></tr><tr><td>RM 1,174.00</td><td>ANA</td></tr><tr><td>RM 50.16</td><td>ZED</td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: @Aika I've updated my answer with the new Data - Was an issue with how locale compare handles decimal separators ( or more, it doesn't ). The fix was to simply remove the `,` from the numerical Strings while sorting